Как считать текст с изображения
Установил тессеракт на убунту
 add-apt-repository -y ppa:alex-p/tesseract-ocr-devel && \
    apt-get -y update && apt install -y tesseract-ocr* && \
    apt install -y libtesseract-dev*`

Испортировал пакет для работы с ним.
go get -t github.com/otiai10/gosseract/v2

Сделал фотку счетчика воды

и положил его в папку с main
Написал код по примеру отсюда
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/otiai10/gosseract/v2"
)

func main() {
    client := gosseract.NewClient()
    defer client.Close()
    client.SetImage("img.png")
    text, err := client.Text()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err, "<---")
        return
    }
    log.Println(text)
}

Запустил код
go run .

На выходе ожидал
2024/07/16 12:53:55 00142899

А получил:
2024/07/16 12:53:55 % oi , i
tes a 4
4

А как собстна получить то что я ожидал?

Я бы предложил собрать и поставить самый свежий тессеракт из гитхаба. Мало ли что было в ppa загружено

Попрбовал другой набор данных. Текст с фото считывает корректно. Код работает. Видимо именно показания счетчика не может считать(((буду искать способ просчитать именно эти данные.
